# Using Streams of the Twitter API in .net Core console application

Tags: .net-core, twitter, stream, console, tweetinvi

I am trying to use the Twitter API to listen for new tweets matching a certain keyword, but I can't seem to get it working. I have been able to successfully push and read tweets using my API credentials, so I know that my credentials are valid.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
using Tweetinvi;
using Tweetinvi.Models;
using Tweetinvi.Parameters;

var consumerKey = "Ef5KN4YsHyEPwcI77JjoPRsTw";
var consumerSecret = "mepw2bvbhaS7BqDlBupXtGrW2f0YBwebxVX932J43PxoSe6CYb";
var accessToken = "1154133280914059271-MLwk85DJekpHWYY2inGQYOF1tfeqFP";
var accessTokenSecret = "MsskhAdaRpDCUR07CgxT8r5vgNMp1X2Ohxxt826mn4slw";

var credentials = new TwitterCredentials(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
var client = new TwitterClient(credentials);

var stream = client.Streams.CreateFilteredStream();
stream.AddTrack("Hello, specific tweet!");

stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text);
};


stream.StartMatchingAnyConditionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


//i can push
client.Tweets.PublishTweetAsync(new PublishTweetParameters("Hello, specific tweet!"));

//i can read
var userTimeline = await client.Timelines.GetUserTimelineAsync("Anton99836536");
var number = userTimeline.Length;
Console.WriteLine(number);

foreach (var item in userTimeline)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
}

//i am authenticated
var user = await client.Users.GetAuthenticatedUserAsync();
Console.WriteLine(user);
```

When I run this code, it seems to connect to the Twitter API, but I never see any tweets being printed to the console, even though I know that there are tweets matching the keyword "Hello, specific tweet!".

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and how I can listen for new tweets using the Twitter API?

PS
I use .net core 6 console and TweetinviAPI" Version="5.0.4"

I try to get messages, that mathed to my filter.